# Specify alternatives in java validation annotations

Tags: java, annotations, hibernate-validator

I'm looking for a way to specify validation constraint that allows alternatives, for example:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp = "^(\\s|\\d|[-+:()])*$")
@Or( // I'm looking for something like this
    @Size(min = 6, max = 20),
    @Size(min = 0, max = 0)
)
public @interface Phone {
    String message() default "Not a valid phone number";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Is it possible using java validator tools?

Comment: In your case, your regular expression can cover it: `@Pattern(regexp = "^|(\\s|\\d|[-+:()]){6,20}$")`  No need for `@Size`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution involving creating several intermediate annotations and using `@ConstraintComposition(CompositionType.OR)`, but maybe someone will propose better solution.

So, first, create Annotation for single branch of alternative:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Size(max = 0)
public @interface Empty {
    String message() default "Should be empty string";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Secondly, create another annotation, that combines your custom annotation with another branch:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ConstraintComposition(CompositionType.OR)
@Size
@Empty
public @interface SizeOrEmpty {
    String message() default "Should be empty or have defined size";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "min") int min();

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "max") int max();
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use two @Size annotations, as it is not a @Repeatable annotation, and, secondly, you cannot override attributes from only one of them with @OverridesAttribute.

Comment: So `@Size` will be `@Repeatable` in Bean Validation 2.0 (so for HV 6) but for now, you can use the `List` container associated with `@Size`.

About `@OverridesAttribute`, you can use `constraintIndex` to apply it to a particular constraint.